# Python engine for trading

Tags: python, amazon-ec2

I have a trading strategy that I want to execute. I want to run the script on amazon EC2. whats is the pythonic way to have it run in background forever?

Essentially the engine will read the market continuously and whenever certain conditions are made execute a trade. For the sake of simplicity it wakes up every 1 minute see if the price has increase if so buy, if not do nothing.

How should I make it run for background forever? currently i have the main function recursively call itself forever. I dont think thats the right approach. I considered pycherry, but that's for webpages.

Any Suggestions?
I am planing to use ubuntu if that makes any difference.

Comment: How long does the function take to execute, if it finds the condition to be True? This could be a good use-case for an AWS Lambda function triggered on a schedule, no server required.

Comment: its not set on an auto schedulerat a function. I consistently want it to run. Depending on the conditions it will check sub-conditions. Obviously one of the outputs is sleep.

Comment: Your question says "it wakes up every 1 minute" -- this is equivalent to running on a schedule that triggers a Lambda function every minute (but if the function takes longer than a minute to run, another Lambda function would be triggered a minute later).

Comment: yea probably not the best explanation....sometimes it goes to sleep many other times its suppose to run continuesly

Answer (score 0):

You could just run a loop:

```
while True:
  sub_function()
  sleep 60
```